# How to change system fonts and Sounds

Tags: applications, adb, android-emulator

How to change system fonts using `adb` and also system sounds using `adb`? I have sucessfully changed system sounds:

```
adb devices
adb remount
adb shell rm /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
adb shell rm /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
cd %~dp0
adb push Lock.ogg     /system/media/audio/ui/
adb push Unlock.ogg  /system/media/audio/ui/
adb shell sync
pause
```

but Sound is not heard on camera click, lock and unlock of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing /system/build.prop and change default item to the files you just added. This should fix the no sound issue.